# How to configure google chart to change from line to column

Tags: php, html, google-visualization

I have a chart that is being showed in an html page that is presenting a chart.

the chart looks like this:

[image]

the code i have for it is:

```
      google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart','bar']});
      google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

      function drawChart() {
        var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
          ['Data', 'Valor de Compra'],
          <?php echo $dados;?>




        var options = {

'backgroundColor': 'transparent',

hAxis: {
            format: 'y M/dd',
            gridlines: {count: 15},
            direction:1, slantedText:true, slantedTextAngle:90,

          },
vAxis: {
gridlines: {color: 'none'},
minValue: 0
}


};

        var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('curve_chart'));

        chart.draw(data, options);
      }
```

The variable $dados is getting this data:

```
[new Date(2018, 11, 04), 3.00],[new Date(2018, 11, 03), 3.20],[new Date(2018, 10, 29), 2.95],[new Date(2018, 10, 29), 3.50],[new Date(2018, 10, 23), 3.20],[new Date(2018, 9, 18), 2.95],[new Date(2018, 9, 18), 2.95],[new Date(2018, 9, 18), 2.95],[new Date(2018, 9, 17), 2.95],[new Date(2018, 9, 17), 2.90],[new Date(2018, 9, 12), 2.95],[new Date(2018, 9, 11), 2.95],[new Date(2018, 9, 11), 2.95],[new Date(2018, 9, 08), 2.20],[new Date(2018, 8, 13), 2.10],[new Date(2018, 8, 13), 2.10],[new Date(2018, 8, 12), 2.00],[new Date(2018, 8, 12), 2.95],[new Date(2018, 8, 08), 2.00],[new Date(2018, 8, 07), 2.10],
        ]);
```

And my goal is to change this layout to something more attracting and good-looking.

I'v been trying to change it to a column chart but so far everything failed... 
I'm sure it must be something really simple...

is there a way to only have the year and the month when a new year start and when a new month starts?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: for a column chart, change --> `google.visualization.LineChart` -- to --> `google.visualization.ColumnChart`

Comment: You could use this - https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/combochart

Answer (score 0):

```
google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['bar']});
  google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
 function drawChart() {
    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
   ['Data', 'Valor de Compra'],
    ]);
var chart = new google.charts.Bar(document.getElementById('columnchart_material'));
```

then

```
 <div id="columnchart_material" style="width: 800px; height: 500px;"></div>
```